# The X property on Y could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Single'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

So I have this fairly compelx LINQ query:

```
        // This query will get the top 10 items sold. 
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<Item, ItemSale>> results = (
            from x in database.ItemSales
            where shiftIDs.Contains(x.shiftID)
            group x by x.item into itemSalesGroup
            orderby itemSalesGroup.Sum(y => y.SalesValue) descending
            select itemSalesGroup
        ).Take(10);
```

And it's crashing on y.SalesValue saying it could not be set to a decimal value.  How do I fix this?  I have tried the following:

```
        orderby itemGroup.Sum(y => (float?)y.SalesValue) ?? 0f descending
        orderby itemGroup.Sum(y => (float?)y.SalesValue ?? 0f) descending
```

Here are the relevent Entity-Framework Code First definition:

```
[Table("ItemSales")]
public class ItemSale {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("ItemID")]
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("itemID")]
    public Item item { get; set; }
    [Column("Shifts_ID")]
    public int shiftID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("shiftID")]
    public Shift shift { get; set; }
    ...
    public float SalesValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the data type of `y.SalesValue`? Also, when you say, "this solution isn't working this time," what do you mean? Is there an error?

Comment: y.SalesValue is current set as type "float", I get the same error with that "solution".

Comment: coalesce the nullable value into a non-nullable value *before* you sum it, rather than after.

Comment: if y.SalesValue is defined as a "float" and not a "float?", then it is already non-nullable. There's no reason to coalesce it.

Answer (score 0):

The expression parameter for [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345537.aspx) cannot return a float. Since it can work with singles, decimals, doubles, etc., it doesn't know which to implicitly cast it to. You have to explicitly cast it.

Try this

```
 orderby itemSalesGroup.Sum(y => (single) (y.SalesValue)) descending
```

Answer (score 0):

In your entity you have Decimal type and you are returning single type from SQL.
Update your SQL query (better) or your entity.